# Is it possible to assert the existence of one or more elements in an array without a for loop?

Tags: c#, xunit

I am testing a function with XUnit. While the test correctly does the job of identifying the existence of "System.DateTime" in a returned Type[] array, I have to do so by looping through the array.  (Why test the existence of a DateTime property I already know of? Because I am learning TDD by playing with some code I'm already familiar with.)

Is there an Assert function that can confirm the existence of an element in array? I am asking question because, while it works, I can't help but wonder if there is any more efficient or compact way of doing this besides looping through the array.

I was hoping there was an undocumented feature in Assert that I could take advantage of.

```
/// <summary>
/// This tests the "GetPropertyTypes(PropertyInfo[] properties)" function to 
/// confirm that any DateTime properties in the "TestClass" are confirmed as existing.
/// </summary>
[Fact]
public void ConfirmDateTimePropertiesInModelExist()
{
    // Arrange
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesInfos = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties();
    int dateTimeCount = 0;

    // Act
    // The names array the list of property types in "TestClass"
    Type[] propertyTypes = ExportToExcelUtilities.GetPropertyTypes(propertiesInfos);

    for (int i = 0; i < propertyTypes.Length; i++)
        if (propertyTypes[i] == typeof(DateTime))
            dateTimeCount++;

    // Assert
    // Assert that the names array contains one or more "System.DateTime" properties.
    Assert.True(dateTimeCount>0,
        "Existing DateTime properties were not identified in the class.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ makes quick work of this:

```
Assert.True(propertyTypes.Any(n => n == typeof(DateTime)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need custom assertions since you can use a standard array commands within your `Assert.True()`.

For example, you could use `Array.FindIndex()`.

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(propertyTypes, t => t == typeof(DateTime));
```

If the index is greater than -1 then an item was found. So to use this in an assertion:

```
Assert.True(
    Array.FindIndex(propertyTypes, t => t == typeof(DateTime)) > -1,
    "Existing DateTime properties were not identified in the class."
);
```